# RxJava map vs Kotlin map

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava

Раньше когда был Java 6 и Rx, при использовании RX подхода, делал mapping так

```
 Single.just(listOf("1", "2", "3", "4"))
            .toObservable()
            .flatMapIterable { it }
            .map { it + "0" }
            .toList()
            .subscribe({
                //log list of 10, 20, 30, 40
                Log.d("TestCase", "${it}")
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
```

В Kotlin все чаще делаю так

```
    Single.just(listOf("1", "2", "3", "4"))
        .map {
            it.map {
                it + "0"
            }
        }
        .subscribe({
            //log list of 10, 20, 30, 40
            Log.d("TestCase", "${it}")
        }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
```

Второй вариант думаю, что выигрывает по скорости и по памяти.

Это криминал?)
p.s. больше похоже на хуливарный вопрос)) но все же, как вы предпочитаете делать?

Comment: Я ровно для этой ситуации написал в своё время extension `inline fun <reified T, R> Single<List<T>>.extensionFunctionName(mapper: (T) -> R): Single<List<R>> = this.map { it.map { mapper(it) } }` На производительность влияет минимально, а выглядит при использовании куда более красиво, чем вложенный маппинг

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну когда вы создаете `flatMapIterable` то вы по сути создаете новый `Observable` потом вы ждете его завершения оператором `toList`.  Все это занимает время. В случае же с **Kotlin** `map` просто функция которая под капотом имеет обычный цикл.

Поэтому если все что вам нужно это из списка объектов получить список полей объектов то конечно вариант с **Kotlin** `map` лучше. `flatMap` же нужно использовать тогда когда вы хотите создать совершенно новый `Observable` в цепочке.